# Need to keep track of 'selected' divs that are highlighted with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I have an 'onclick' event handler for a div and the div has a nested read-only text field whose text font changes from normal to **bold** when selected inside the onclick handler:

```
 <div class="itemlistRowContainer" id="topmostDiv_ID" onclick="handleRowClick(this);">
    <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" id="itemName_id"
           name="itemName" value="$itemname" readonly="readonly"
           class="itemListReadonlyTextFieldUnselected"></input>
 </div>
```

Here is the `onclick` handler:

```
  function handleRowClick(theElement)
  {
      var childTextElementArrayOfSizeOne = theElement.getElementsByTagName("input");
      var theTextField = childTextElementArrayOfSizeOne[0];

      theTextField.className = "itemListReadonlyTextFieldSelected";
  }
```

Here's the `itemListReadonlyTextFieldSelected` CSS class:

```
   .itemListReadonlyTextFieldSelected
   {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: RGB(255,0,0);
   }
```

I have several of these `div-with-nested-readonly-text-field` on my page.

When the user clicks on one of them, the above `onclick` handler successfully changes the nested text input's font to bold and color red.  So the selecting part -- bold+red text -- works fine.  But I need to de-select the old selection when the user clicks elsewhere.

So my question is -- how can I keep track of the 'currently selected div+text input' item -- so that when a different div+text input is clicked on, I can change back the previously selected div+text input to black, not-bold text, using this style?

```
   .itemListReadonlyTextFieldUnelected
   {
        font-weight: normal;
        color: RGB(0,0,0);
   }
```

I *immediately* thought "I'll just save the 'currently selected' div and text input DOM elements in my SESSION - ahh nope this is client side javascript."  Session variables are my go-to for stuff like this on server-side code.

My current technology requirements are php, javascript and html (jquery = no.)

What's a good way to keep track of the previously selected div+text input?

A brute-force method would be to traverse the tree of ELEMENTs on the page and find the one div that has a nested text element whose `className = "itemListReadonlyTextFieldSelected"` but I'd rather smash my big toe with a gott-dang sledgehammer than have someone during a code review slap me upside the head after seeing something like that.

Comment: If you get slapped, slap them right back and say, "I wouldn't have to go these lengths if you dolts would allow us to use jQuery. `$('.itemlistRowContainer input').removeClass('itemListReadonlyTextFieldUnselected');` would unselect any selected input and you could then set the newly selected one as you are accustomed to doing now (although jQuery would still make that easier).

Comment: +1 Thanks Robusto, the code reviews are bruising, if you disagree you get labeled as disagreeable, if you're too accepting they call you a smarmy deuce.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about assigning it to a variable?

```
var currentlySelectedTextElement;

function handleRowClick(theElement)
{
    // un-highlight the currently highlighted element
    if (currentlySelectedTextElement){
        currentlySelectedTextElement.className = "";
    }

    var childTextElementArrayOfSizeOne = theElement.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var theTextField = childTextElementArrayOfSizeOne[0];

    theTextField.className = "itemListReadonlyTextFieldSelected";

    // save the reference so you can un-highlight it later
    currentlySelectedTextElement = theTextField;
}
```

Comment: Thx Brandan, adding 'onclick=handleBodyClick' to my 'body' tag has the newly selected item not getting selected, the selecting broke. So another SO post mentioned 'bubbling up' Methinks the click on a div+text area DOES select it, but the same mouse click 'bubbles up' to the new onclick=handleBodyClick() method I added -- and immediately DE-selects what was just selected. I had to remove the onclick=handleBodyClick() from my page's 'body' tag -- because a call to theTextField.stopPropagation() failed to stop the body's handleBodyClick() from immediately un-doing the selection.

Comment: Saving the selected div in a 'global' variable at file scope in the topmost javascript block allowed me to immediately find the previously-selected Div and then de-select its inner text field.

Comment: Okay. I updated my answer to avoid the event bubbling problem.